# Create new column in excel based on condition

Tags: excel, csv

curently in my csv i have the following field

```
 No Name 

 1  Samsung s5
 2  samsung s6
 3  Nokia 3112
```

Now i need to make an extra column in excel namely brand . If the name of the mobile starting with samsung then it's brand must be Samsung
How to do this(AUTOMATICALLY FOR ALL COLOUMN) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to split after the first space, with Name in B2, use in C2

=left(B2,find(" ",B2)-1)

Copy down.

Or use Text to Columns with Space as the delimiter.

Or, in Excel 2013 and later, type the first value in C2, the next one in C3 and use Flash Fill to do the rest.

Or use Power Query to import the CSV and split the data in the query. This means you can repeat the query if the CSV file changes.

Comment: i have one doubt one of my column value is Electronics>Tablets  . How can i split this in to two .

Comment: Split at the chevron.

Comment: Please explain ,or give the formula

Comment: Provide a data sample and the expected result.